# Unable to locate python3.8 on switching user sessions in CentOS

Tags: python-3.x, bash, centos, centos7

Below are my OS specifications:

```
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"
```

[I installed python 3.8.1 as per steps described here](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-python-on-3-on-centos/) on a Virtual Machine.

When i use a different SSH session, I am able to run python3.8 normally. When I switch users using
`sudo su` and then come back to same user using `su <user>` I get the below error

**`bash: python3.8: command not found`**

Why is this so? Can anyone help? Is it a bash error?

Comment: is `/usr/local/bin` in your PATH?

Comment: Why didn't you install it with `yum install -y python3` instead? Anyway, I think you should check your `PATH` like @jordanm suggested

Comment: @jordanm yes it's in my path

Comment: @ChrisBrownie55 it installs python 3.6 and I want to try python 3.8

Comment: Do you have the full path to the file? If so, what is it? Can you execute the command with the full path?

Comment: the sys.path command points to '/usr/local/lib/python3.8' directory